# bound for $\cosh$

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to show that $1.543<\cosh(1)$. I tried to use Taylor expansion to 
with reminder to got the interval of possible values.
What I have 
$$
 1.541 <\cosh(1)
$$ 
any comment.

Comment: $\cosh(1) > 1.5430$. Recheck your calculations...

Comment: try another term or three in your taylor expansion?

Comment: $\cosh(x) = \sum \frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}$ so summing up the first $N-1$ terms we have that the error is less than $\frac{2}{(2N)!}$.

Comment: $1+1/2+1/24+1/720=1.54305\dots<\cosh 1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\cosh(1) = \frac{1}{2} (e+e^{-1}) = \frac{1}{2} 2 \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2k)!} $$ because the odd terms in the two Taylor series for $e$ and $e^{-1}$ cancel.
Since all the terms in this sum are positive,
$$\cosh(1) > \sum_{k=0}^3 \frac{1}{(2k)!} = 1 + \frac12 + \frac{1}{24} + \frac{1}{720}> 1.543$$